# Why I can't use KSImage plug in?

Tags: ios, plugins

I have downloaded the NSImage plug-in, but it did not work on my project.

My X-code Version is 7.3.1 and KSImage's Version is 7.3.

I also have deleted the old KSImage, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: "it did not work" is not an adequate description of a problem

Comment: it means , the plug-in shold show the Image which in my Assets File, but it didn't do anything now.